Shift DataGridView up by one row
I've found this code to shift a column down by one row:
private void ShiftColumnByOneRow(DataGridView dataGridView, int columnIndex)
{
    if (dataGridView.Rows.Count > 1 && columnIndex >= 0 && columnIndex < dataGridView.Columns.Count)
    {
        // Store the value of the last cell in the column
        var lastValue = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[columnIndex].Value;

        // Shift each cell value down by one row
        for (int i = dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Value = dataGridView.Rows[i - 1].Cells[columnIndex].Value;
        }

        // Set the first cell value to the last cell value
        dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[columnIndex].Value = lastValue;
    }
}

//Call this method when needed:

// Example usage
ShiftColumnByOneRow(yourDataGridView, columnIndex);

How do I shift it up?
I've tried:
dataGridView.Rows[i-1].Cells[columnIndex].Value = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[columnIndex].Value;

That turns all the rows in the column blank.

Hint: think about why the original for loop runs from higher indexes to lower ones and how this is related to the direction of the shift.

MVVM
In modern programming there is a tendency to separate your data (=Model) with how your data is shown to the operator (=View). To link the Model to your View, an adapter class is needed, quite often called the ViewModel. Together these three classes are abbreviated to MVVM. If you are not familiar with this, consider to read some background information about MVVM.
Seperating the data from how this data is shown to the operator, enables changing the view without having to change the model. For instance, you can show your data in a graph, but you could also show the same data in a table.
Separated model and view, enables you to change the model, without having to change the view. For instance, you can fetch your data from a file, from a database or even from the internet. These are changes to the Model. If for some reason you can't provide the same interface, the adapter class ViewModel can convert the layout of the model to the View. The view doesn't have to be changed.
Separating the Model from the View also enables you to reuse the Model and to unit test the Model without needing a View. Similarly you can test the way that the data is shown to the operator with mock data. You don't need the database with the actual data, your Model can be a list of items to display.
Back to your question
When people use a DataGridView they tend to fiddle directly with Columns and Rows. It is way easier to separated the data from the way it is represented to the operator. This way, you simply have to rearrange your sequence of shown data, to rearrange the way it is shown to the operator.
You didn't tell us what kind of data you are displaying. To make communicating easier, let's assume you are displaying a sequence of Products:
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public int Stock {get; set;}
}

And somewhere you have a method to fetch all Products that must be displayed:
IEnumerable<Product> FetchProductsToDisplay() {...}

Implementation is out of scope of this question.
Using Visual Studio Designer you have added a DataGridView to your form and added some Columns to your DataGridView. Maybe you show all properties of the Product, but maybe you don't wan't to show all properties, for instance, the Product's Description might be too long to display in the table. Simpley don't create DataGridViewColumns that you never want to show. If you have columns that sometimes are shown, and sometimes are hidden, use property Use property DataGridViewColumn.Visible.
In the constructor of your Form, you define which column shows which property using DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName
public MyForm() : Form
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // define which column shows which Product property
    this.ColumnProductId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Id);
    this.ColumnProductName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.ColumnProductPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Price);
    ... // etc.
}

The method to display the data depends on whether you only want to display the data, or whether you want the operator to edit the data, or manipulate the data otherwise, like sorting by column.
If display only is enough, you can use a List<Product>. If you need editing, it is better to use a BindingList<Product>.
BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

To fill your DataGridView is now a one-liner:
this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(this.FetchProductsToDisplay().ToList();

Because you've uses a BindingList, the operator can edit Products. He can add and remove Products. Whe he's finished editing the operator can press the Apply Now button, or Ok:
void OnButtonApplyNow_Presses(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ProcessEditedProducts();
}

void ProcessEditedProducts()
{
    ICollection<Product> editedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts();

    // find out which Products are Added / Removed / Changed
    // and process the changes
    this.ProcessProducts(editedProducts);
}

Or, you want to shift all rows one up and put the first row at the end, or shift all rows one down, and put the last row in front.
void ShiftDisplayedProductsUp()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> displayedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;

    // use LinQ to move the first element to the end
    IEnumerable<Product> shiftedProducts = displayedProducts
        .Skip(1)
        .Concat(displayedProducts.Take(1));
    
    // display the shifted products:
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>(shiftedProducts.ToList());
}

And presto, your shifted List is shown. Of course you could also use BindingList methods to remove the first Product from the BindingList and add it to the end. I'm not sure if that is efficient.
Might be handy: access selected Products
For completeness, it might be handy to access the current Product, or the selected Product:
Product CurrentProduct => (Product)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<Product> SelectedProducts => this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Product>();

Summary
By separating the data from the way it is shown to the operator, your code look much cleaner. The data can be reused for other purposes. It can be unit tested wihout a DataGridView and you can test the DataGridView with a simple mock sequence of Products.
To achieve this, I only needed to define which column shows which Product property, and only one simple Property: DisplayedProducts.
By using this property, you can directly access changes that the operator made. Changes that you make to the collection are immediately displayed to the operator.
Finally: did you notice that the separation of data and View made most procedures very simple? Usually you only fetch the data, you manipulate the data and display it again. No need to access Columns and Rows.
